# Не подменяется robots.txt в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

Я наблюдаю старую версию robots даже после замены ее физически и плагином robots.txt editor. Ощущение что он в кеше где-то, но я уверен что кеш очищен и со стороны хостинга кеша тоже нет.
Кеш на сайте обеспечивает wp supercache. Также есть плагин для сео, который тоже может генерировать robots, но проблема точно не в нем.

Comment: К физическим файлам ВП (не подключённых в коде плагинов) не причастен. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: По идее да. Но, при наличии физического (или при замене в плагине) я должен увидеть изменения. Он принципиально показывает старую версию, каким способом не меняй.

Comment: Похоже как будто на кеш.

Comment: Куков точно нет.

Comment: Выключил все плагины.

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема, это был кеш на стороне сервера в клаудфлаер.